# How can I clean out my gutters while still on the ground?

Tags: gutters, cleaning

My roof is taller than I'm comfortable getting on a ladder. I've got a couple weeds/trees starting to grow in them. Is there a tool that would somehow let me scrape or use water-pressure to clean the gutters?

Comment: My parents had kids for this.  Sort of expensive I know (especially if they go to college), but they are good for lots of stuff you don't want to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may want to look at something like the [Gutter Cleaning Wand](https://web.archive.org/web/20121029085737/http://www.smarthome.com:80/31262/Gutter-Cleaner-Wand-Rain-Gutter-Cleaning-Device-58582/p.aspx):

> [image: man cleaning his gutter]
> <sub>(source: [smarthome.com](https://cache3.smarthome.com/images/31262big.jpg))</sub>

> You don't need to hire a professional to clean out your clogged rain gutters. Attach the Gutter Cleaner Wand to any standard garden hose, and you'll be able to clear out those debris-filled rain gutters yourself. This heavy-duty hose attachment has a telescoping wand that extends from 41.5 inches to 68.5 inches to get to those hard-to-reach spots along your roof.
>
> - Rain gutter cleaner attaches to any standard garden hose
> - Spray nozzle directs water flow to blast away debris
> - Gutter cleaning device extends to 68.5 inches to aid in reaching remote areas

Comment: That looks exactly like the kind of thing that I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Along with the gutter cleaner you'll want to buy head-to-toe raingear.  The guy in the picture is lucky because he's cleaning his gutters 15 minutes after they were installed: unless you're as lucky as him you're going to get *covered* in mud. :)

Answer (score 2):

The [iRobot Looj](http://store.irobot.com/default/looj-gutter-cleaning/irobot-looj-330/L330020.html) may help you - it is a gutter-cleaning robot. I've never tried one, but I do have a Roomba (which I can attest works quite well) and these are the guys that make military/bomb squad robots.

You still have to get on a ladder to get it in, of course, but you don't actually have to climb onto the roof.